# Bicycle layer for android maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an app for use with my bicycle.  Does anyone know if the bicycling layer is available for development on android yet?

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by Peter, osmdroid allows you to set the tile source with

```
mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.CYCLEMAP);
```

It looks like this:

[image: Cycle map]

I'm not sure what all the different colours mean!

Answer (score 0):

[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has a bicycle layer. There is an Android Lib: [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

Comment: Thanks for the info...I'll look into that but was hoping that google has the bike layer available.